# Jquery UI draggable creates a whitespace at the bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

The idea of the page is to drag, rotate and resize the object. It all works well but then I encountered a problem wherein if I drag the object to the most bottom part (The object is contained in the canvas). It creates a whitespace as shown in the photo attached. It does not have a problem on the other sides except the bottom. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Here's the initialization of the jquery draggable:

```
$(".object-clone.object-valves,.object-clone.object-pumps").draggable({
    containment: "#canvas-repository",
    stack: ".object-clone",
    cursor: "move",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $globalSaveState = false;
        if ($globalResizeMode) {
            $(ui.helper).css('z-index', '1010');
        }
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        var $objectPosition = ui.helper.offset();
        var $dblPositionX = $objectPosition.left;
        var $dblPositionY = $objectPosition.top;
        var $canvasPosition = $("#canvas-repository").offset();
        var $dblCanvasPositionY = $canvasPosition.top;
        var $intObjectCount = $(ui.helper).data('item');
        var $dblCanvasWidth = $('#canvas-repository').width();
        var $dblCanvasHeight = $('#canvas-repository').height();
        var $dblObjectCloneSize = $dblCanvasWidth * $dblArea;
        var $dblArea = $(ui.helper).attr('data-area');
        $dblPositionY = $dblPositionY - $dblCanvasPositionY;
        var $percentagePositionX = ($dblPositionX) / $dblCanvasWidth;
        var $percentagePositionY = ($dblPositionY) / $dblCanvasHeight;
        var $roundedPercentagePositionX = Math.round($percentagePositionX * 100) / 100;
        var $roundedPercentagePositionY = Math.round($percentagePositionY * 100) / 100;
        $(ui.helper).attr("data-vertical", $roundedPercentagePositionX).attr("data-horizontal", $roundedPercentagePositionY).css('width', $dblObjectCloneSize).css('height', $dblObjectCloneSize).css('left', ($roundedPercentagePositionX * 100) + "%").css('top', ($roundedPercentagePositionY * 100) + "vh");
    }
});
```

> Here is the image with whitespace, when the object is at bottom

[image: Image with whitespace]

> Here is the image  without whitespace, when the object is at the
>   center or other sides, unscrollable and no whitespace

[image: Image without whitespace]

Comment: I see you use draggable and resizable so maybe it's a CSS issue `overflow:visible` on the container.

Comment: @Core972 Could you explain that to me more? Thank you so much

Comment: If the picture with the man with the red helmet is higher than the container

Comment: @Core972 Thankyou for your kindness. I figured it out. It has nothing to do with the draggable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! It was just dumbness after all. It is because of the rotation that made the image exceed the container. Closed!

[image]